# setInterval won't execute internal function

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm trying to create a timer in javascript.
The sec variable won't increment. Any idea why this is happening?

```
<script>
var sec = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    start_timer();
}, 1000);

function start_timer() 
{
        sec++;          
}
</script>
```

How I call the variable:

First, I have a form that calls getCurrentTime()

```
<button type="button" onclick=" <?php getCurrentTime(); ?>"  class="unstyled-button imageButtonLeft" >
```

getCurrentTime stores the sec variable into setTime(), then I use getTime() to print it.

```
function getCurrentTime()
{
    //Unserialize
    $s1 = file_get_contents('store');
    $moodCalculator = unserialize($s1);

    $time = "<script>document.writeln(sec);</script>";
    $moodCalculator->setTime($time);

    //Serialize
    $s1 = serialize($moodCalculator);
    file_put_contents('store', $s1);
}

echo $moodCalculator->getTime();
```

Is it maybe possible that getCurrentTime() is getting called after the form has already been sent? 'Cause that would explain why "sec" results to 0 when I print it.

Comment: What makes you think `sec` isn't incrementing? Seems to be incrementing just fine for me

Comment: ^^ since nothing is using `sec`...? Also, just FWIW, there's no need for the wrapper function there...

Comment: your code works fine , the problem is from somewhere else , you should give more detail on how you are using this in your scripts

Comment: @BrighFaith I have added further information. 
If I execute start_timer() manually, my code will print 1, that is why I think is setInterval that doesn't work.